# Problem on using indexOn on deeper nested item

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

[image]I have search a lot on stackoverflow and read many questions 
I was having 3 indexOn problem 2 of them are solved and 1 remains
I am sorting database and have indexOn on "favorite" and "poet" which runs successfully but I need one more indexOn for numbers inside heart node.
query is running successfully but I am getting indexOn warning in android studio

I have tried using variables in place of numbers in database rule but still getting warning

> Using an unspecified index. Your data will be downloaded and filtered on the client. Consider adding '".indexOn": "heart/+91916*******"' at gazal to your security and Firebase Database rules for better performance

```java
queryFav = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
             .getReference(reference).orderByChild(child).equalTo("heart");
```

above query run successfully but what should be indexOn rule

Answer (score 2):

The message you get means you are running a query that has `orderBy("heart/+91916*******")` on a node named `gazal`. To efficiently run that query, you need to have an index on `heart/+91916*******` to that node in your security rules. But since the `+91916*******` part of that index probably is dynamic (i.e. you'll have a different value of `+91916*******` for every user of the app), you'll have to add an index for each user. That is not feasible.

In other words: you current data structure makes it easy to read the users who have hearted a specific poem. It does however not make it easy to determine the poems that a specific user has hearted. To make that equally easy, you'll want to add an additional data structure"

```
"user_hearts": {
  "+91916*******": {
    "-KjYiXzl1ancR8Pi3MfQ": true
  }
}
```

With the above structure you can easily read the `user_hearts` node for the user you're interested in, and then read the poems one by one if needed.

Also see:

- [Firebase query if child of child contains a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value)
- [Firebase Realtime Database - index on location containing uid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57736429/firebase-realtime-database-index-on-location-containing-uid/57738853#57738853)

Comment: Thanks for Frank for such quick response as expected from you. But i have approx 10k+ such nodes so changing structure of database is difficult for me, is it impossible for having indexon on my existing structure?